# Landlord Right to Enter While Tenant Not Present (Texas)

Tags: rental-property, landlord, texas, rent

We rent an apartment in Texas and will be moving in the summer.  Our landlord would like to schedule showings to new prospective tenants.  Our landlord has given us notice of the showing times (24 hours), however they have chosen not to consult us regarding scheduling a time during which we will be home.  We believe this is a reasonable accommodation, to request a time for the showing during which we will be home.

Our lease is similar to the standard TAA lease and includes the following language:

> Before accessing the Unit, Landlord or anyone authorized by Landlord will attempt to first contact Tenant, but may enter the Unit at reasonable times without notice to make repeiars or to show the Unit to prospective tenants or buyers, inspectors, fire marshals, lenders, appraisers, or insurance agents.  Additionally, Landlord or anyone authorized by Landlord may peacefully enter the Unit at reasonable times without first attempting to contact Tenant and without notice to: (1) survey or review the Unit's condition and take photographs to document the condition; (2) make emergency repairs; (3) exercise a contractual or statutory lien; (4) leave written notices; or (5) seize nonexempt property if Tenant is in default.

However, Chapter 94 of the Texas property code has the following language:

> Sec. 94.004.  LANDLORD'S RIGHT OF ENTRY.  (a)  Except as provided by this chapter, the landlord may not enter a tenant's manufactured home unless:
> (1)  the tenant is present and gives consent;  or
> (2)  the tenant has previously given written consent.
> (b)  The written consent under Subsection (a)(2) must specify the date and time entry is permitted and is valid only for the date and time specified.  The tenant may revoke the consent without penalty at any time by notifying the landlord in writing that the consent has been revoked.
> (c)  The landlord may enter the tenant's manufactured home in a reasonable manner and at a reasonable time if:
> (1)  an emergency exists;  or
> (2)  the tenant abandons the manufactured home.[1]

and

> Sec. 94.003.  WAIVER OF RIGHTS AND DUTIES.  A provision in a lease agreement or a manufactured home community rule that purports to waive a right or to exempt a landlord or a tenant from a duty or from liability under this chapter is void.[1]

Ref: [Texas Property Code](https://statutes.capitol.texas.gov/Docs/PR/htm/PR.94.htm)

Thus there appears to be a contradiction between the lease and state law.

Do we have the right to refuse entry and request a reasonable time during which we will be present?  Does the language in the lease or state law take precedence?  Are there any relevant court cases addressing this question?  Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't your final quotation make it clear that the lease condition (may enter at reasonable time **without consent** to show the Unit to prospective tenants or buyers) is void?

Comment: You rent an apartment: why are you quoting laws about mobile homes?

Comment: A manufactured home isn't quite the same as a mobile home (the former includes anything built in a factory and subsequently moved to a site), but it would certainly be unusual for an apartment to be built in such a way. You need to establish the general rules for other types of home.